# Error in dimnames(res) of MCA (FactoMineR)

Tags: r, analysis

i am doing MCA with FactoMineR but always have the same error message!

This is my data `valqualis` to be analysed. 156 rows and 20 columns.

```
P1 20 4.708846 111  11 0011 0010 11  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
P1 3  4.790977 10NA 10 0111 0001 0NA 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

And this is the code I am doing to run it.

```
require(FactoMineR)
require(factoextra)

#ACM
res.mca<-MCA(valqualis)
```

But each time I have the following error:

`Error in dimnames(res) <- list(attributes(tab)$row.names, listModa) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the cause of the error!

After doing `summary(valqualis)` I found that I had 2 columns which included quantitative values, so I changed them into `factor` with the following code:

```
valqualis$X1 <- as.factor(valqualis$X1)
valqualis$X2 <- as.factor(valqualis$X2)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for posting this solution!  Saved me a lot of time. :)